# Android Virtual Microphone

Tags: android, java, audio

I would like to know whether some tool exists to create a virtual microphone on Android.

For example, when I connect my headset, my phone uses the microphone on the headset. Instead, I want to be able to:

- specify a file to be read as the virtual microphone's input stream
- alternatively, specify the input from another device

I've heard these sort of things are impossible due to hardware restrictions, but I feel like there should be a way to create virtual devices which can emulate a real microphone.

What library, API, app, or software can I use to create a virtual microphone in Android?

Comment: It exactly fits the help center requirements!! I have defined a purpose and some objective requirements and looking for Android libraries (software) to accomplish my task! It's not code related or too specific!

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/953/583

Comment: Hi Arijoon, I think your question can be reworded to get reopened. Asking *if* something is possible, and asking for documentation, is off-topic here. Currently, your question would attract answers that provide links to documentation and explanations/discussions how to implement it. But we want answers that recommend specific software(s). Don’t care if it’s technically possible, directly ask what you need, e.g.: "I’m looking for a library that […]". -- Please [edit] your question, then we can try to reopen it. (-- All this is only *my* opinion about your question, though.)

Comment: ok thanks for the reponse. Also thanks to ComFreek for seeking more information regarding this closure. I asked this question on StackOverflow and someone said, it should have been asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Xposed related hooks might help.

There's [Android virtual cam](https://github.com/w2016561536/android_virtual_cam/blob/77fda649d5352b84ed06e8718fdfab97d6663128/app/src/main/java/com/example/vcam/VideoToFrames.java)

But I want to rephrase that, according to your need, a more realistic media source shall be implemented in `rtmp://` protocol, instead of static file. I am actively seeking help for live streaming on Android virtual camera/microphone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/63783)